# After upgrade of Gradle to the version 3.0.1 something generates redundant jacoco.exec file

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I have the following modules:

- app (com.android.application)
- testlibrary (com.android.library)

After upgrade of Gradle to the version 3.0.1, Jacoco plugin generates redundant and not valid jacoco.exec file in the app (com.android.application) module’s root folder after execution of tests. This file is generated when in testlibrary (com.android.library) module I set **testCoverageEnabled true**. If I set in testlibrary **testCoverageEnabled false**, then jacoco.exec file is not generated.

**Expected Behavior**

jacoco.exec file shouldn’t be generated in the root folder of app module after execution of tests, regardless testCoverageEnabled flag set to true or false in the testlibrary module.

**Current Behavior**

After execution of tests, jacoco.exec file is created in the root folder of the app module if in the testlibrary module the testCoverageEnabled flag set to true.

**Context**

I’m trying to upgrade to the Gradle 3.0.1 version from the Gradle 2.2.2 version. But after upgrade and execution of all tests, I noticed that a new redundant jacoco.exec file was generated inside of app’s root directory.

**Steps to Reproduce**

GitHub repo to showcase the issue: https://github.com/DenysShovhenia/Test

Steps to reproduce:

- Open project in Android Studio
- Run testDebugUnitTest task of Test(root) module
- Note the newly created jacoco.exec file in the root folder of app module

I hope somebody can help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug which for now is not closed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67872367

After a lot of research, I have found some workarounds.

1) Add this to the modules where this file is generated.

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all {
                // workaround for generation of unexpected jacoco.exec file in project directory
                systemProperty 'jacoco-agent.destfile', buildDir.path + '/jacoco.exec'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Create in the library module under library/src/debug/resources folder the file **jacoco-agent.properties**.

And add to this file next line:

```
destfile=build/jacoco/coverage.exec
```

So, in this way you can just replace this files to the build folder.

Additional variants:

3) Set testCoverageEnabled to false for library module.

4) Don't use code from the library in tests for the app module.

Useful link:
http://www.qalearningguide.com/2017/10/code-coverage-for-android-using-jacoco.html